# I am hated by man and kids alike

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> I am invisible
>
> I mould modern technologies
>
> I shape music, art, and architecture
>
> I keep planes from falling from the sky
>
> I am small as a decimal point
>
> But as big as the universe
>
> I am the root of all things
>
> But loathed by many kids and adults alike

### What am I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are

> mathematics

I am invisible

> Mathematics are not tangible

I mould modern technologies

> Mathematics are the basis of science

I shape music, art, and architecture

> Mathematics rule music (waves), art (e.g. gold number, perspective) and architecture (e.g. mechanics of materials)

I keep planes from falling from the sky

> Mathematics are the basis of science, which makes the planes fly

I am small as a decimal point

> A decimal point is part of the maths

But as big as the universe
I am the root of all things

> Mathematics are the basis of science, which describes how the universe works

But loathed by many kids and adults alike

> Many don't like mathematics

Comment: Yep.  That's the one!  I knew that would go quick.

Comment: A nice first puzzle!

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> economics/the invisible hand?

I am invisible

> True

I mould modern technologies

> Economic demand drives technologies that are created

I shape music, art, and architecture

> Demand also shapes music, art, and architecture because of people’s preferences

I keep planes from falling from the sky

> Because shooting down planes or hiring bad pilots is economically infeasible

I am small as a decimal point

> _Micro_economics

But as big as the universe

> _Macro_economics

I am the root of all things

> It’s based in money and supply-demand is the root of everything

But loathed by many kids and adults alike

> Kids don’t like economics class, adults don’t like getting screwed by the markets

Comment: In the right direction, but no. Sorry.  But thanks for being the first answer for my first puzzle here..!

Comment: It’s a great first puzzle @Snow! Welcome to Puzzling.SE!

Answer (score 1):

Are you...

> Physics

I am invisible

> You can't see physics, they just do what they do

I mould modern technologies

> All technologies use physics in some way

I shape music, art, and architecture

> Music - physics of sound, Art - physics of light, Archictecture - physics of keeping buildings standing.

I keep planes from falling from the sky

> Physics of pressure differences keeps planes in the air

I am small as a decimal point

> Physics can be applied to really small things

But as big as the universe

> Physics is how the universe works

I am the root of all things

> Physics is how everything works

But loathed by many kids and adults alike

> Kids and adults don't like having to do physics

Comment: Close, but not the one I was after.  Nice thinking though!

Comment: Darn! I thought for sure I had the answer.